# how to implement calculator on edittext?

Tags: android, calculator

In my android apps,i want to press edittext the follwing popup calculator shown.when i enter calculation and  press "ok" button result will stored in edittext.how to do this?give me any example code?

thanks in advance..

[image]

Comment: While entering amount i have use the quick amount input to enter small amounts up to 99999 or use the calculator to do basic arithmetic calculations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make an Activity that does all the Calculator functionality you need (I'll leave that as an excercise.. :P)

In your original Activity, on the click even of your `EditText`, call the Calculator Activity using `startActivityForResult()`

The Calculator Acitivity should use `setResult(RESULT_SUCESS, simple_intent_with_result_as_extra)`

When the Calculator Activity Exits, the `onActivityResult` will be called on your original Activity with that Intent you passed earlier.

Extract the result from the extras and display it in that EditText.